# Azure Functions C# Http Trigger does not return response

Tags: c#, azure, httpresponse, azure-functions

If have a simple HTTP triggered function in C# which just doesn't return the result:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    string jobId = req.Headers.GetValues("scheduler-jobid").FirstOrDefault();
    string executionTime = req.Headers.GetValues("scheduler-expected-execution-time").FirstOrDefault();

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,new {
        JobId = jobId,
        ExecutionTime = executionTime}
    );
}
```

I checked with POSTMAN that HTTP headers are set correctly but just get a 200 OK without a response body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In hindsight the solution is obvious:
I had to define a HTTP Response output and without changing the code above the Azure Functions runtime automatically wires in the `req.CreateResponse`.

[image: defining a HTTP Response output binding]